# calculate and swap result in some columns on certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms

hie geeks, 
I have a table ACNT which is like this

```
 P_date     P_Supplier  P_parti   P_opnbal  P_Credit     P_Debit P_Remaining 
 NULL         varsha    opening    2000        0            0       2000
 2014-01-25  varsha     purchase    0          500          0        500
 NULL        nipun      opening    1000        0            0       1000
 2015-01-28  nipun      purchase    0          200          0        200
 2016-01-25  varsha     purchase    0          350          0        350
```

now I fire this query to get sum or all columns

```
SELECT P_sname, SUM(P_opnbal) AS opneningbal, SUM(P_credit) AS credit, SUM(P_debit) AS debit, SUM(P_opnbal) + SUM(P_credit) - SUM(P_debit) AS closingbal
FROM ACNT
GROUP BY P_sname
ORDER BY P_sname DESC
```

so I get this result

```
P_Supplier  P_opnbal    P_Credit    P_Debit CLossing
varsha      2000        850          0       2850
nipun       1000        200          0       1200
```

but now I want this columns to be calculated in between particular date range.
for eg. 
if I want data  in between `2015-01-28` and `2016-01-28`. 
then all the data present in table of date `2014-01-28` should be shown as Opening balance and credit should be 0 if no entry in given date range is present.

see in 1st table, that row has date `2014-01-28`then its `P_credit` value should be plus with its `P_opnbal` value i.i 2000 . so it should show 2500 as opening balance as result.
desired result should be like

```
Supplier   Opnbal   credit  Debit   closing balance
varsha     2500     350     0        2850
nipun      1000     200     0        1200
```

I know i will need more than 1 query for this,I am in learning phase , this is what i tried

```
SELECT P_sname, opneningbal + credit AS openingbal, credit, debit, closingbal
FROM 
(SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT P_sname, SUM(P_opnbal) AS opneningbal, SUM(P_credit) AS credit, SUM(P_debit) AS debit, SUM(P_opnbal) + SUM(P_credit)- SUM(P_debit) AS closingbal
 FROM ACNT
WHERE (P_date BETWEEN '2015-01-25' AND '2016-01-25')
GROUP BY P_sname
ORDER BY P_sname DESC) AS abc
```

but i am not getting desired result, Please help me to improve this query. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our chat in [asp.net room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net)

I came across to your final query should be

```
SELECT P_sname, (isnull((select sum(isnull(ac.P_credit,0)) from ACNT as ac where ac.P_sname=abc.P_sname and P_date<'2015-01-25'),0) 
+(select top(1) isnull(nt.p_opnbal,0) from acnt as nt where nt.p_sname=abc.P_sname and p_parti='Opening')) as opening_bal, credit, debit, ((isnull((select sum(isnull(ac.P_credit,0)) from ACNT as ac where ac.P_sname=abc.P_sname and P_date<'2015-01-25'),0) 
+(select top(1) isnull(nt.p_opnbal,0) from acnt as nt where nt.p_sname=abc.P_sname and p_parti='Opening'))+(credit-debit)) as closingBal 
FROM (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT P_sname, SUM(P_opnbal) AS opneningbal, SUM(P_credit) AS credit, SUM(P_debit) AS debit, SUM(P_opnbal) + SUM(P_credit) 
- SUM(P_debit) AS closingbal, P_date 
FROM ACNT 
GROUP BY P_sname, P_date 
ORDER BY P_sname DESC) AS abc 
WHERE (P_date BETWEEN '2015-01-25' AND '2016-01-25')
```

Tip: there is more scope of improvements **scaler functions** can minimize your query also you can do this by only one select query also

Thanks.